# Converting mouse coordinates to label coordinates in Qt

Tags: qt, position, mouseevent, coordinates

I'm in trouble with such issue: 
I need to select some area with rect on my label, I'm using QRubberBand to do this, but there is one problem: I need to know coordinates of current rect on my label, so I'm in trouble with it, because mouseEvent->pos() give coordinates which starts with top left corner on mainWindow border, moreover i've rotate standard coords on label (from top left to bottom left corner, as we paint them usually). 

Anybody knows how can I do this translation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
QPoint mappedPos = myLabel->mapFromParent(myWindow, mouseEvent->pos());
```

Also, `QTransform` provides a number of `map()` functions which should be able to get you the point in rotated coordinates as well.

See:

[QWidget::mapFromParent()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qwidget.html#mapFromParent)

[QTransform::map()](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtransform.html#map-3)